# Confusion regarding the 'new' keyword in C#, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Maybe a silly question, but having difficulty understanding it.

```
public class A
{
  public void Message()
    {
      Debug.Log("Some Message")
    }
}

public class B: MonoBehaviour
{
  A obj1 = new A(); //instance of object is made and constructor is called
  A obj2;           // object is made
  
  obj1.Message();
  obj2.Message();

 void Start(){}
 void Update(){}
}
```

What's the purpose of 'new' keyword if in both cases, the object is able to use methods of the class

Comment: `obj2` will not be initialized and you get a NullReferenceExeption ...

Comment: `if in both cases, the object is able to use methods of the class` , that is not the case..

Comment: `A obj1 = new A()` - an instance of class `A` is created and it's default constructor is invoked. `A obj2` - an instance of class `A` is not created. `obj2` should be null at this point, so I would think `obj2.Message()` would throw an object reference not set to instance of an object error.

Comment: This is not valid syntax. A minimal reproducible example is needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is your class `A` tagged `[Serializable]`? In this case the Unity Inspector would automatically initialize that field with a valid instance .... ... either way ... your method calls should probably be placed inside of a method ....

Comment: You have probably simplified your code so much, it doesn't represent the original problem anymore. Read [mre] and create one that does.

Comment: @StackOverthrow this question is downvoted because OP didn't provide a full code example but reduced it to something that doesn't even compile .... therefore any answers will be purely based on assumptions and not really helpful

Comment: Normally you don’t make monobehaviours with new. As you would in normal basic c#

Answer (score 1):

```
A obj2;           // object is made
```

The object is not instantiated at this time, you only told here that you have a variable with the name obj2, and it is hold reference to nothing, in case of class it is `null`. You have a class named A and in it, you have a method called Message() and compiler in compile-time have a signal you have Message method defined, and that it is. In this case, this code should throw an exception NullReferenceException

Comment: I disagree. For me, the code won't even compile: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6vruwV. The variable is instantiated, which is very different than `null`.

Comment: actually the Unity Inspector will initialize this field in case `A` is `[Serializable]` and the field `public` which would mean the field is serialized which I suspect is the case here ... I'ld say OP reduced the code too much

Comment: @gunr2171 In the Unity context it makes perfect sense - Unity is managing an instance for you that is configurable in the UI inspector. This is done via serialization.

Comment: @asawyer as a person who has done zero Unity and a lot of c#, I stand thoroughly corrected, and also slightly confused.

Comment: @gunr2171 It's not the only weird thing Unity does. https://medium.com/@nosuchstudio/why-are-null-coalescing-operators-evil-in-unity-16f5a88d6071

Comment: It would still not compile since you can not call the methods outside a method ....  until OP doesn't provide the actual code all answers are purely based on assumptions ...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few quirks to Unity which may be tripping you up here. Actually, obj2 is not null, because it is of type "A" (not a Monobehavior). Since Class B is derived from Monobehavior, all of its "class variables" (the ones defined in immediate scope) will be instanced by the Inspector automatically. You can read about that [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/774814/public-variable-instance-of-custom-class-is-never.html).

In other words, obj2 will still be usable. This is a property of custom classes in regards to how they are loaded from MonoBehaviors. If class A was also a MonoBehavior, then it would be nullable here, and you would see it as an empty variable in your inspector when Class B is put onto a GameObject. This is the case where Message() would not work, since obj2 would actually be null. *Note there are other complications though--if Class A is a MonoBehavior, then you shouldn't be using Constructors on it, you should be using AddComponent(). Also, you can't define two MonoBehaviors in the same script file.*

Finally, I'm not sure of the specifics here since I haven't tested it, but obj1.Message() may not be able to be called from where you're currently doing it. Typically code is run using the Callback functions provided by the MonoBehavior inheritance, i.e. Start(), Update(), etc. In order to call obj1.Message() at the start of the game, you need to run it from the Start() method. Let me know if you have any questions and I can clear up anything you find confusing!

EDIT: This is only true if obj2 appears in the inspector--if it is public and the class A is tagged as Serializable.

Comment: `all` is not true. The type `A` would need to be `[Serializable]` and the field either `public` or tagged `[SerializeField]` in order to be serialized ... both is not the case in provided code so this answer I would have written myself already would be purely based on assumptions until OP provides the actual code

Comment: Yes that's correct, my bad--I assumed too much about the usage here. After performing my own tests and reading up on it it seems the Editor is what stops custom classes from being null. In other words, if it does not appear in the Editor (if it is private and not serialized) then it is still nullable.